# Aurelia version upgrade policy

Tags: version, compatibility, updates, aurelia

One thing I'd like to know about Aurelia is if it follows a compatibility-oriented update model similar to the Ember's one; I'm citing [from a recent interesting article about Ember](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/05/13/emberjs-an-antidote-to-your-hype-fatigue.html):

> All the changes made in the 1.x releases are supposed to be backwards compatible, so in theory, you can upgrade from 1.3 all the way up to 1.11 with relatively few issues.
>
> The way they do this is to incrementally deprecate things in the framework that they plan to remove, but they will keep the features (and tests) around for the entire 1.x series or otherwise shim them with compatibility layers. So while you are encouraged to resolve these deprecations as soon as possible, you are given a very long timeframe to do so.

I didn't found anything on the subject, but I discovered that Rob Eisenberg favours Ember above React or Angular, because it shares some of his design principles.

Does anybody knows anything about this?

Comment: If you look at the release notes it's mentioned fairly often http://blog.durandal.io/2016/08/03/releases-august-3-2016/, even the beta had very few breaking changes, I don't remember seeing anything about features being removed.

Comment: "In any case, you can rest assured we aren't going to do a major re-write and then simply change the major version. Even major changes we may need to make will be incremental in nature." Maybe it's not the same thing, but it's close enough.

Comment: A good argument might be that every team member is actually using Aurelia on real projects, day in day out. As such we need to depend on this pledge as much as other devs have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the official [go live blog article](http://blog.durandal.io/2016/07/27/aurelia-1-0-is-here/)

> If we need to make a breaking change, Aurelia is modular enough to make that easier on us and on you. Any changes of that nature will be announced well in advance and will always be designated by a major version change in the associated library. Any removal of features will be proceeded by a deprecation period.

As such we, the Aurelia Team, do follow Semver. This even includes official plugins like the Validation, I18N. All of us have been through the pain of having to cope with extensive, undocumented or unexpected changes with other libraries/frameworks as such we are working hard to save you from that experience.

The most important aspect is the deprecation period plus transition guidelines if any features are removed.